# Replace Swedish characters in filenames

Tags: media

Are there any robust way to search an entire WordPress site and rename all uploaded files to just containing latin chars?

All of a sudden I'm having problems with my JetPack galleries where images contain for example åäö (swedish chars).

I have found some plugin that can rename file names but the ones I found for both rename file names and replace references in the database were all so unused.

Any tips?

Comment: open a bug with jetpack?

Comment: I did that. Thanks! Hope for a reply. Would be nice with a plugin to clean up all non latin chars anyway though...

Comment: there should be nothing wrong with non latin characters. supporting them is something that was solved years ago.

Comment: I've been in contact with them and tried to fix it but it seems to be an unknown issue still.